# Post login execution

Tags: spring, spring-security

I need to do some processing only after the user has successfully logged in the system. I have thought that I can do a RESTful method and setting it as the default-target-url so when the login is successful it goes to this url and then I can redirect to the real index of my web application.

```
<form-login login-page='/login.htm' default-target-url='/home.htm' always-use-default-target='true' />
```

The problem is that this processing can be executed by calling its URL so it could be executed by any user at any time. I want to make sure it is only executed after login.
Is there any way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm - read your title quickly - though it seemed a bit harsh on the user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by creating a handler which extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler and by doing my custom implementation in onAuthenticationSuccess method.

To call this handler after the succeeded Login I set authentication-success-handler-ref property in the XML configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do this in a Servlet Filter?

```
/**
 * @see javax.servlet.Filter#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
 *      javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain)
 */
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    // Do post processing here if we have a valid session for the user
}
```

And in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PostLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.scoreout.web.servlet.filter.PostLoginFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PostLoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/login.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done something similar but with the handlers provided by Spring Security.